Unexpected memory usage when training transformer models with LoRA and quantization
I am training models using transformers, accelerate, bitsandbytes and PEFT. I recently got a second graphics card (RTX 3090) and am seeing a decent increase in training speed. However when experimenting with Lora and quantization, I found certain combinations weren't reducing memory as I'd expect.
If I understand correctly, accelerate uses DistributedDataParallel (DDP) which copies the model onto both graphics card's memory. So with Lora and BNB turned off, I'd expect to see both cards use 2.6GB. I'm confused as to why they're using over 7GB with accelerate implemented.
I'm using accelerate to utilise 2 graphics cards, and have confirmed both are being utilised 100%.
In all tests I'm using DistilBERT (66 million params), the same data, batch size of 16. Memory clears to 0 after each test. I'm only changing the model loading:
# 4 bit config
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(  
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type= "nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype= torch.bfloat16,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant= False,
)

# 8bit config
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_8bit=True,
    llm_int8_threshold=6.0,
    llm_int8_skip_modules=None,
)

# Lora
peft_config = LoraConfig(
    task_type="SEQ_CLS", # sequence classification
    lora_alpha=16,
    lora_dropout=0.1,
    r=8,
    bias="none",
    target_modules=["query", "key", "value", "query_global", "key_global", "value_global"]
)

model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
model = prepare_model_for_kbit_training(model)



